# Delete and then load fresh data into MySQL table inside a transaction

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with content that needs to be replaced periodically with new XML data. It is not a huge amount of data (in the megabytes) and the statements below execute fairly quickly.

```
truncate table my_table; 

load xml local infile path_to_file 
into table my_table;
```

I want the refresh to occur inside a transaction so that data reads would wait and not get empty results. Would placing the above statements in a transaction be a proper way to accomplish this? Is there anything that I need to be concerned about?

Edit:

Upon further research, I discovered another way of doing this:

```
create table my_table_2 like my_table;

load xml local infile path_to_file 
into table my_table_2;

rename table my_table to backup_table, my_table_2 to my_table;

drop table backup_table;
```

Any issues with this approach? Which of the two approaches is better?

Comment: truncating a table inside a transaction causes an implicit commit: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: @MarcB What about using a "delete from" statement? My concern was that the primary key column, which is an auto_increment field may grow out of control.

Comment: if it's only a few megabytes of data (which can still be a huge number of records), you might be better off with a simple `delete from table where 1=1`, and then reset the auto_increment value.

Comment: Thanks! Can you post the code in an answer so that I can accept it? Do I need the "where 1=1"? Can't I just use "delete from my_table"? Any other issues you see?

Comment: some mysql versions have "i_am_a_dummy" mode enabled (yes, that's a real setting) that prevent delete/update queries that don't have a where clause. you can try it without and maybe it'll work.

Comment: It does work in my case - I guess I am not a dummy :)